# Understanding Composite Pattern via C#, Remove(T item) function implementation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, composite

I am working on the **Composite Pattern**, using the examples from C# 3.0 Design Patterns by Judith Bishop (Page 55).

The question I am stacking on concerns the function from **Composite class:
public IComponent Remove(T item)** 
What is the sense of making the following IF statement

```
 if (_holder != null)
            {
                (_holder as Composite<T>)._items.Remove(p);
                return _holder;
            }
```

in

```
public IComponent<T> Remove(T item)
    {
        _holder = this;
        IComponent<T> p = _holder.Find(item);
        if (_holder != null)
        {
            (_holder as Composite<T>)._items.Remove(p);
            return _holder;
        }
        else
        {
            return this;
        }
    }

    //Recursively looks for an item
    //Returns its reference or else null
    public IComponent<T> Find(T item)
    {
        _holder = this;
        if(Item.Equals(item))
        {
            return this;
        }
        IComponent<T> found = null;
        foreach(IComponent<T> comp in _items)
        {
            found = comp.Find(item);
            if(found != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
```

As far as I am concerned, _holder variable is always assigned in both **Remove** and **Find** functions and therefore cannot be null. 
Do they mean **p** referece to be checked for null instead?

**Interface IComponent**

```
 public interface IComponent<T>
{
    void Add(IComponent<T> component);
    IComponent<T> Remove(T s);
    IComponent<T> Find(T s);
    string Display(int depth);
    T Item { get; set; }
}
```

**Component class implementation:**

```
    class Component<T> : IComponent<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }

    public Component(T item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }

    public void Add(IComponent<T> item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot add to Single item!");
    }

    public IComponent<T> Remove(T item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot remove directly the Single item");
        return this;
    }

    public IComponent<T> Find(T item)
    {
        if (Item.Equals(item))
        {
            return this;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public string Display(int depth)
    {
        return string.Format("-{0}---{1}", depth, Item);
    }
}
```

**Composite class implementation:**

```
public class Composite<T> : IComponent<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
    private List<IComponent<T>> _items = new List<IComponent<T>>();
    private IComponent<T> _holder;

    public Composite(T item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }

    public void Add(IComponent<T> item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }

    //Finds the item from a particular point in the structure
    //and returns the composite from which it was removed
    //If not found, return the point as given
    public IComponent<T> Remove(T item)
    {
        _holder = this;
        IComponent<T> p = _holder.Find(item);
        if (_holder != null)
        {
            (_holder as Composite<T>)._items.Remove(p);
            return _holder;
        }
        else
        {
            return this;
        }
    }

    //Recursively looks for an item
    //Returns its reference or else null
    public IComponent<T> Find(T item)
    {
        _holder = this;
        if(Item.Equals(item))
        {
            return this;
        }
        IComponent<T> found = null;
        foreach(IComponent<T> comp in _items)
        {
            found = comp.Find(item);
            if(found != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically you could make it be `null` through some evil reflection shenanigans, but somehow I doubt that that's why that check is there.  It's probably just a mistake, as you mentioned.

Comment: Resharper be like "YOU SHOULD CHECK FOR NULL MMKKK" so then the author is all like "k, hit alt+enter, fix it for me."  In reality though, making the _holder assignment to begin with doesn't make too much sense, could just use "this"

Comment: @MattClark Clark, I suppose they make use of _holder assigning to this at the beginning because of the recursive look in all the components inside the composite, that can also be composites. It means, that if we do find a Component, that is not a Composite and the only item in the hierarchy (i mean it should be a leaf), the holder should be assigned to null. I am not sure about my assumption anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check is meant for p and not this because this cannot be null.

```
_holder = this;
    IComponent<T> p = _holder.Find(item);
    if (_holder != null)
```

this cannot be null
so _holder cannot be null either
but the find can return null
and it is very logical to check the result of find before doing a remove.

Another possibility is that

```
_holder as Composite<T> is null ?
```

so

```
if (_holder as Composite<T>==null)
```

is also a valid check.

Comment: Firstly, I was wondering if _holder could be changed in Find method during recursion, as not all of the components are the actual composites, but as _holder is still assigned right in the start of Find method, makes no sense for my assumption.

Comment: _holder cannot just become null because of the find operation.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this is a mistake, also because of

```
     IComponent<T> p = _holder.Find(item); //THIS LINE !
    if (_holder != null)
    {
        (_holder as Composite<T>)._items.Remove(p);
        return _holder;
    }
```

If we somehow concerned about `_holder` become a `null` (reflection, multithreading...)  why we don't check for that on the line before ? What does guarantee me that on that line `_holder` is *not* a `null`, if we assume that it can become such in this case somehow ?

So, most probably, an error.